# Python DEAP, how to stop the evolution when the fitness doesn't increase after X generations?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

I want to stop the genetic algorithm when the fitness doesn't increase.

I'm using the DEAP library in python.

Typically, I have the following log file:

```
    gen nevals  mean        max     
    0   100 0.352431    0.578592
    1   83  -0.533964   0.719633
    2   82  -0.567494   0.719633
    3   81  -0.396759   0.751318
    4   74  -0.340427   0.87888
    5   80  -0.29756    0.888443
    6   86  -0.509486   0.907789
    7   85  -0.335586   1.06199
    8   69  -0.23967    1.12339
    9   73  -0.10727    1.20622
    10  88  -0.181696   1.20622
    11  77  -0.188449   1.20622
    12  72  0.135398    1.25254
    13  67  0.0304611   1.26931
    14  74  -0.0436463  1.3181
    15  70  0.289306    1.37582
    16  79  -0.0441134  1.37151
    17  73  0.339611    1.37204
    18  68  -0.137938   1.37204
    19  76  0.000527522 1.40034
    20  84  0.198005    1.40078
    21  69  0.243705    1.4306
    22  74  0.11812 1.4306
    23  83  0.16235 1.4306
    24  82  0.270455    1.43492
    25  76  -0.200259   1.43492
    26  77  0.157181    1.43492
    27  74  0.210868    1.43492
```

I initially set ngen = 200, but as you can see, the fitness function achieve a local maximum at 22th generation. So I want to stop the genetic algorithm when this happens.

Comment: You can adapt your algorithm with a simple break condition.
All statistics are stores in the [logbook](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    random.seed(64)
    pop = toolbox.population(n=100)
    CXPB, MUTPB = 0.5, 0.2
    print "Start of evolution"
    fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))
    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit
    print "  Evaluated %i individuals" % len(pop)
    fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]
    g = 0
    while max(fits) < 0.67 and g < 1000000:
        g = g + 1
        print "-- Generation %i --" % g
        offspring = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))
        offspring = list(map(toolbox.clone, offspring))
        for child1, child2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]):
            if random.random() < CXPB:
                toolbox.mate(child1, child2)
                del child1.fitness.values
                del child2.fitness.values
        for mutant in offspring:
            if random.random() < MUTPB:
                toolbox.mutate(mutant)
                del mutant.fitness.values
        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit
        pop[:] = offspring
        fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]
        print "fitness-- ",max(fits)
    print "-- End of (successful) evolution --"
    best_ind = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
    triangle_to_image(best_ind).save('best.jpg')
```

**this will stop the code when a fitness value desired is reached** or a particular number of generations are over

*you can set is in such a way that it stops when fitness doesn't change for some time* i.e when it reaches local maxim and gets stuck there

**line 12** 
**this example stops when fitness crosses 0.67** 
and then saves the result

**this is the way to do it when you are not using something like hall of fame**
dont know how to do it then if you find it tell me too

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I was looking into that issue recently too.
Following the research I've done recently here is what I found:

1. There's a DEAP example which implements CMA-ES algorithm. It has stopping criteria included ([Python DEAP, how to stop the evolution when the fitness doesn't increase after X generations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724381/python-deap-how-to-stop-the-evolution-when-the-fitness-doesnt-increase-after-x/51401581#51401581))
2. There is a dissertation thesis worth reading on that: https://heal.heuristiclab.com/system/files/diss%20gkr2.pdf
3. The above mentioned solution implements what's mentioned in Issue: https://github.com/DEAP/deap/issues/271

I haven't yet tried none of the above but I'm more than sure that it will work.

Comment: Seems kind of strange to link to a different answer in your own answer...